# Using the unique function in r for a data.table where you want to stratify which variables you want removed

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, unique, ranking

I have several large data tables based on customers with different characteristic that I merged.

The resulting merged data table has duplicated rows that I now want to eliminate.

Here is a snapshot of how it is constructed.

**Input**

| customerID | color | sport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | soccer |
| 1 | red | basketball |
| 1 | blue | basketball |
| 2 | green | tennis |
| 2 | green | basketball |
| 2 | red | basketball |
| 3 | blue | soccer |
| 3 | green | soccer |

I would like to remove the duplicates by ranking the variables in each column (minus the customerID which would be unique) in this order and removing the lower ranked variables where they occur:

color: green>red>blue
sport: soccer>basketball>tennis

This would yield one characteristic per customerID with no duplicates as follows:

**Output**

| customerID | color | sport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | soccer |
| 2 | green | basketball |
| 3 | green | soccer |

How do I go about doing so? I have used the unique function before; however, that removes duplicated rows indiscriminately.

**Edit:**

Follow up question:

Say I want to do some descriptive stats and find out the number of customers who have **soccer** and **basketball** listed under sport. Is there a way to do that with this dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Using factors one could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# data
d <- tribble(
  ~"customerID",    ~"color",   ~"sport",
    1,              "red",      "soccer",
    1,              "red",      "basketball",
    1,              "blue",     "basketball",
    2,              "green",    "tennis",
    2,              "green",    "basketball",
    2,              "red",      "basketball",
    3,              "blue",     "soccer",
    3,              "green",    "soccer",
)

# as data.table
setDT(d)

# factors
d[, color := factor(color, levels = c("green", "red", "blue"))]
d[, sport := factor(sport, levels = c("soccer", "basketball", "tennis"))]

# order by factors, take the first row of each group
d[order(color, sport), first(.SD, 1), by = .(customerID)]
```

This gives:

```
customerID color sport
<dbl>     <fctr> <fctr>
3   green   soccer      
2   green   basketball      
1   red     soccer
```

Number of unique IDs with soccer AND basketball. Using list columns:

```
d1 <- d[, .(list(sport)), by = customerID]
d1["soccer" %in% unlist(V1) * "basketball" %in% unlist(V1), .N]
```